# Issues using onchange() and onkeypress() together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input that needs to be a numerical digit and needs to update a label when the value is changed.

```
<input id="shares" name="shares" type="text" maxlength="3" onchange="game_board.update_shares(this);this.oldvalue = this.value;" onkeypress="return game_board.isNumberKey(event)">
```

The onkeypress function is needed to ensure that the user can only enter in numbers, and the onchange will update my label with the new information.

The onkeypress function is working great, I am only able to type numbers. However, the onchange function is doing nothing.

validation function:

```
this.isNumberKey = function(evt){
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
  && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
   return false;
  }

return true;};
```

Update Function:

```
this.update_shares = function(o){
alert("test");
$(".dollar_amount").html("$" + "value" + ".00");};
```

Comment: jQuery will do all the needed *translations*, `evt.which` is quite enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you might as well use the jQuery event handlers as well:

**HTML**

```
<input id="shares" name="shares" type="text" maxlength="3" />
<div class="dollar_amount"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#shares").on("keydown", function (evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

$("#shares").on("change", function () {
    var o = $(this).val();
    $(".dollar_amount").html("$" + o + ".00");
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/e43pE/1/

Does this suit your needs? Or are you needing to keep `this.update_shares = function(o)`?

Comment: Wow, looks like there is a lot more to Jquery than I thought. lol

Thank you for this.

Comment: Okay, I am missing something.. Should this code work any differently if it is in an external file? I don't think so, but neither function is working now.

Also this may or may not matter, the ".dollar_amount" is in a dialog box.

Comment: Since it's jQuery, you'll need to put that code in a `$(document).ready()` function. So, if it's in an external file, first include the jQuery file before the above code, then include the above code wrapped in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Wow. I am still having issues. Looks like its back to the drawing board. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: I'm not really sure, I dont have access to a java-script console right now to determine where the break down is happening.
I will in about 2 hours. As soon as I can if I still have issues I'll let you know.

However, right not the functions acting like they are not being called correctly. Very possible I did something wrong. I live by the console.debug function. 

I'll let you know what happens.  Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Therefore, what you want is update the label as the value changes. If I were you, I would do it on the keypress event. I mean, something like:

```
this.isNumberKey = function(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
    }
    $(".dollar_amount").html("$" + "value" + ".00");};
    return true;
};
```

Comment: The issue is that I needed the update to be different from the validation. Thank you for the assistance.